# Changing the date used within a query which has been provided by a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a query which will be used within a reporting dashboard. the query needs to pull a date from a parameter which is feed from a datetime control within the dash board.

The issue i have is that the date time control will show the current date or can be changed using a drop down calender. I need the query to look at the date provided and perform a bit of an if statement.

If the date provided is the same month as the current month. I need the date used within the query to be the last day of the previous month. ELSE it should use the last day of the month selected.

I have tried several variations writing my code into the Where Clause but have so far not come to any success. Even just trying to get the query to give me the last day of the previous month (Code below) has not worked.

Any ideas would be welcome. I am really stuck on this.

```
SELECT A.ETLKEY, A.EFFECTIVEDATE, A.ACTUAL,
FROM DBO.View
WHERE (A.EFFECTIVEDATE = (DateAdd("d", -1, CDate(
           "01/"+CStr(Format(&EndDate(),"MM/yyyy"))))))
```

Second attempt

```
DECLARE @dtDate DATE
SET @dtDate = &Enddate
--'Month/day/year'
SELECT Case 
    When @dtDate = '08/01/2016'
    -- Last day of previous month, as this month will have no date in it
    Then DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@dtDate),0))
    -- Last day of month stated.
    Else DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@dtDate)+1,0))
```

So final working Code for anyone who might find this useful in the futrue

```
DECLARE @dtDate DATETime
SET @dtDate = &Enddate
--'Month/day/year'
SELECT Case 
    --compares month from parameter to todays month
    When DATEPART(mm,@dtDate) = DATEPART(mm,GETDATE())
    -- Last day of previous month, as this month will have no date in it
    Then DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@dtDate),0))
    -- Last day of month stated.
    Else DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@dtDate)+1,0))
    END
```

Comment: Sorry yes its not mySQL i click the wrong tag Sorry

Comment: please provide the actual dbms you're using, this highly depends on the dbms. is this mssql? oracle? postgres? date/time functions are very different between those ...

Comment: I am using Rocket NG, which i beleive java Script and has SQl functions

Comment: I have tried to look for more details but cant find any. The visual display seems to work in JavaScript, but the the query editor seems to be SQL although what type i am unsure

Comment: well, CDate sounds like Access

Comment: ah so CDate is probably the wrong comand then. I was adviced to use it by someone else who said it should would in an SQL report. but it hasn't been working

Comment: oh? So ... you should probably test which dbms you have. If I read correctly, `select @@version` could provide some insight (mysql and mssql) or `SELECT banner FROM v$version WHERE rownum=1` will throw an error, that contains the version number of an oracle database (if it is one). perhaps it's mysql after all ^^

Comment: Alright, it would be way simpler, if you could look, where the database connection is defined/initialized, maybe some config file ... will provide the insight (don't post the actual server/username/password that might be included), look for something that sounds like one of postgres(ql), oracle, db2, mysql, mssql, (or something else with "sql")

Comment: to form the connection it uses a MS SQL driver. through JDBC so a java connection.

Comment: moved away from previous attempt towards this

Comment: sorry it wont let me post it, so added it to the oridinal post. Basicly using this to determin the date then will use date in the query. but get an error saying unknown syntax near )

Comment: You haven't ended your case statement. Literally just add the word `end` after the `else` section.

Comment: Thankyou so much That now works perfectly. I will just add it to the full querry now.